# Specifying Ahead of Time Both the Color of All Drop Caps and That Their Associated Text be Bold

Tags: macros, color, bold, lettrine, drop-cap

Consider the code

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\setcounter{DefaultLines}{3}
\setlength{\DefaultFindent}{0em}
\setlength{\DefaultNindent}{.17em}
\renewcommand{\LettrineFontHook}{\usefont{U}{yinit}{m}{n}}
\renewcommand{\DefaultLoversize}{-0.67}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{LARGE}
\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}{5.75in}
\lettrine{W}{e cannot} \textbf{\textit{solve our problems with the same thinking we used when we created them.}}
\end{minipage}

\vskip 25pt

\begin{minipage}{5.75in}
\lettrine{\color{red}{W}}{\color{red}{e cannot}} \textbf{\textit{solve our problems with the same thinking we used when we created them.}}
\end{minipage}
\end{center}
\end{LARGE}
\end{document}
```

which produces the output

[image]

Looking at the first of the two quotes, I would like to make `E CANNOT` both red and bold. As you can see from the code, I forced the red color that I want; however, when I tried to make the text bold by using `\textbf`, I lost the small caps.

QUESTION: As documents that I work on often have contain many drop caps, I would like to be able to specify not only the color of the drop cap and its associated text ("`E CANNOT`", in this case) ahead of time for all drop caps in the document, but also, I would like to designate ahead of time for LaTeX to make the associated text of all drop caps bold. How may I accomplish this?

Thank you.

Comment: Add \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer Thanks for the `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` suggestion. I can now add bold by force (i.e., `\textbf`) on a particular basis without losing the smallcaps. It does not, however, universally make the associated text bold though, but it helps.

Comment: you can control the font of the second argument with `\renewcommand\LettrineTextFont{\scshape\bfseries\color{red}}`

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer Many thanks again. That works great! Would you perhaps know if there's a way to similarly color every lettrine letter by a preamble command as well? That would complete the answer to the question posed. Thank you again for this very helpful comment.

Comment: why don't you check the documentation? It even mention the color of the lettrine on page 4.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer Yes.  It tells me about the `\renewcommand{\LettrineFontHook}` command and how I may specify the color with it. But when I augment that command in the above code by `\color{red}` as follows: `\renewcommand{\LettrineFontHook}{\color[red]\usefont{U}{yinit}{m}{n}}` --- I get the error "Undefined color model 'red'. I must be doing something wrong. Hopefully, I'll figure it out. Thanks again.

Comment: it should be `\color{red}` with braces, not with brakets.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer Many thanks! (The reason I used brackets is because that is what the documentation specified to do: `\renewcommand{\LettrineFontHook}{\color[gray]{0.5}}`). PLEASE (if you would) post all you have helped me with as an answer so that I may upvote it and accept it. Thanks again for all your help.

Comment: @mlchristians The option `[gray]` is the colour model, and the grayscale value in that model is`{0.5}`. Other colour models are `[rgb]`, `[RGB]` and so on. Each model has its own value-format.